# Generate Jupyter Notebook password without Python

Tags: bash, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, sha1, salt

Following https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/common.html#docker-options you can define your own password for starting Jupyter Notebook when using docker image.

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 jupyter/base-notebook start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.password='sha1:74ba40f8a388:c913541b7ee99d15d5ed31d4226bf7838f83a50e'
```

I can only find that the used salted sha1 password can be generated using IPython.lib.passwd(). But, how to generate it without using Python? I do not have IPython or maybe just do not know how to use it. I am on CentOS Stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approximate the original password generation algorithm with the following small shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

passphrase="hello, world"

# generate salt
salt=$(openssl rand -hex 6)

# generate hash
algorithm=sha1
echo -n "$(echo ${passphrase} | iconv -t utf-8)${salt}" | openssl dgst -${algorithm} | awk -v alg="${algorithm}" -v salt="${salt}" '{print alg ":" salt ":" $NF}'
```

**Why does this work (sort of)?**

You mentioned that the original password generating algorithm is based on `IPython.lib.passwd` which is actually implemented in [`IPython.lib.security`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister). The relevant code portions are:

```py
salt_len = 12

h = hashlib.new(algorithm)
salt = ('%0' + str(salt_len) + 'x') % random.getrandbits(4 * salt_len)
h.update(encode(passphrase, 'utf-8') + encode(salt, 'ascii'))

return ':'.join((algorithm, salt, h.hexdigest()))
```

In order to understand what this code does, it is useful to first look at the produced output once again. From your question, we have an example of the generated password:

> sha1:74ba40f8a388:c913541b7ee99d15d5ed31d4226bf7838f83a50e

The colons divide this string into three parts:

```
<hashing-algorithm> : <salt> : <hashed salted passphrase>
```

With that in mind, let's go through the `IPython` code. At the top, we define the number of characters used for the salt. Let's double check - yes, indeed, in your example the salt consists of 12 characters: `74ba40f8a388`.

Next, a new instance `h` of a hashing algorithm is created. As we know from your example, the value for the `algorithm` parameter is `"sha1"`.

After that, a random salt is generated. Now this line is interesting. If you don't have a Python background, the percentage sign (`%`) might remind you of an integer [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). But in fact, it is not, because the parameter left of the percentage sign is of type `string`. So, rather, this is ([now kind of obsolete](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)) Python syntax for formatting a string, quite similar to `printf` in `C`, except that you're not limited to *printing* in Python, you can use this formatting operation anywhere you have a string.

Given that we know that `salt_len` is `12`, this line basically reduces to:

```
salt = '%012x' % random.getrandbits(48)
```

which means that the salt should be a bit string of 48 bits, formatted as a 12 digit hexadecimal string.

Why 48 bits? Well, you need two hexadecimal character to encode a single byte (`0x00` through `0xff`), so if we're aiming for 12 characters, we need 6 bytes = 48 bits.

The last line before the `return` applies the `sha1` algorithm to the concatenation of the utf-8-encoded passphrase and the ascii-encoded salt.

Finally, the algorithm, the salt, and the hashed salted passphrase are returned as a concatenated string with colons (`:`) as separators.

**Now**, if you inspect the shell script I posted above you will find more or less the same steps in there as well. But there is a notable difference, and that's why I wrote initially that it is just an approximation of the actual algorithm.

The difference is in the way the salt is generated. Although the result is in both cases a 12-digit hexadecimal string, the `IPython` code uses an implementation of the [Mersenne-Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister), while my script is based on [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hashing. This will result in different cryptographic properties.

But you can decide for yourself whether it is acceptable or not. Unfortunately, I was not able to source an implementation of the Mersenne Twister that's available just from the command line. But if you know of a good alternative for generating the salt, feel free to update the script. The remainder of it should not be affected.

---

Alternatively, if you prefer a solution without [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/), you could also use this version:

```
#!/bin/bash

passphrase="hello, world"

# generate salt
salt=$(tr -dc a-f0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c 12)

# generate hash
algorithm=sha1
echo -n "$(echo ${passphrase} | iconv -t utf-8)${salt}" | sha1sum | awk -v alg="${algorithm}" -v salt="${salt}" '{print alg ":" salt ":" $1}'
```

But unfortunately, I cannot state anything about the properties of a salt generated via `/dev/urandom` this way.